# Unable to capture AfterUpdate event with a custom event handler

Tags: vba, events, userform

I have a Userform with several `TextBox`, and I need to check their values so I have created a single event handler using a class module with a `WithEvent` private object.
The `Change` event handler works just fine, but not the `AfterUpdate` handler (the same goes for `BeforeEvent`, `Enter`, `Exit`).

Here's a short example of the problem:

```
' class name is NumberBox
Private WithEvents nbTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal t As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set nbTextBox = t
End Property

Private Sub nbTextBox_Change()
    Debug.Print "Change " & nbTextBox.Value ' Working
End Sub

Private Sub nbTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    Debug.Print "AfterUpdate " & nbTextBox.Value 'not working
End Sub
```

The UserForm code looks like this:

```
Private col As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Set col = New Collection

    Dim c1 As MSForms.TextBox, c2 As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim tb1 As NumberBox, tb2 As NumberBox

    Set c1 = Controls("TextBox1")
    Set c2 = Controls("TextBox2")

    Set tb1 = New NumberBox
    Set tb2 = New NumberBox

    Set tb1.TextBox = c1
    Set tb2.TextBox = c2

    col.Add tb1
    col.Add tb2


End Sub
```

I have tried to change `UserForm.TextBox` to `UserForm.Control` but I get a `object or class does not support the set of events`, even though `Userform.Control` is the class which define the `AfterUpdate` event according to the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you ever got an answer to this question, but your observations are correct. The events available to WithEvents controls are only a subset of the events normally available to that type of control. As you note, the Enter, Exit, BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate events aren't available to variables declared as WithEvents.

I don't see any authoritative website on this, even in [Chip Pearson's page that covers WithEvents](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx), but if you search on "vba withevents no enter afterupdate exit event" you'll find several discussions (including this one, which I landed on while looking for an authoritative page for a [blog post](http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-class-multiple-control-types/) reference).

You can tell which events are available by clicking on the control and event dropdowns in the class:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did not find any simple solution, however from what i read it seemed possible to achieve it by creating a class that would handle all Userform events and then redispath these events to the right control. But it was too complicated for what I entended to do in the first place so I gave up

Answer (score -1):

```
Private WithEvents Control1 As MSForms.Control
```

Will allow you to bind to events common to all controls: Enter, Exit, BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate

Correction. This does not work, and creates a run time error.