# Certain events not firing for combobox

Tags: vba, events, combobox, wrapper, userform

I have a userform with programmatically created comboboxes, which I need to run events on. As per the advise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738405/programmatically-create-event-listener-in-vba), I created a wrapper class which I put around each such combobox ("event listener").

This is the rough content of the clsEvntListnr class module

```
Public WithEvents cb As MSForms.ComboBox
Public frm As UserForm    

Private Sub cb_Change()
    CollectGarbage
End Sub    

Private Sub cb_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    'stuff
End Sub    

Private Sub cb_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'stuff
End Sub    

Private Sub cb_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    'stuff
End Sub

Private Sub cb_DropButtonClick()
    'stuff
End Sub

Private Sub cb_Enter()
    'stuff
End Sub

Private Sub cb_Exit()
    'stuff
End Sub

Private Sub cb_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'stuff
End Sub

Private Sub cb_Click()
    'stuff
End Sub

Private Sub cb_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'stuff
End Sub

Private Sub cb_AfterUpdate()
    'stuff
End Sub
```

This is how the comboboxes are created (as a part of an event for another combobox). The C_COMBOS at the end is a globally declared collection.

```
Private Sub cbTransaction_Change()
      Dim oEvtListnr As clsEventListener
      'other stuff and declarations

      For i = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
            Set ctrl = Me.Controls.Add("forms.combobox.1", "ctrlTb" & i, True)
            Set oEvtListnr = New clsEventListener
            Set oEvtListnr.cb = ctrl
            Set oEvtListnr.frm = Me
            C_COMBOS.Add oEvtListnr
      next i
End sub
```

Now the behaviour is mostly as expected with the exceptions that certain event just will not fire. From the events I defined in the class module, the following do fire:

```
cb_KeyDown, cb_KeyPress, cb_KeyUp, cb_DropButtonClick, cb_DblClick, cb_MouseUp
```

while these do not:

```
cb_Change, cb_Click, cb_Enter, cb_Exit, cb_AfterUpdate
```

I have made the obvious tests by putting in breaks into these events and indeed they simply do not fire up. Any idea what may be the issue?

Comment: You may have encountered this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995931/unable-to-capture-afterupdate-event-with-a-custom-event-handler

Comment: @SJR very instructive, however apparently it addresses only about half of the question - Enter, Exit and AfterUpdate seem to be unsupported by WithEvents, however Change and Click should still work...

Comment: Change and Click will work in your  example above. You could "catch" every event (also Enter, Exit, before- and AfterUpdate) with the help of the ConnectToConnectionPoint API as long you don't work on a Mac