# Collection of textbox userform controls (specifically _BeforeUpdate) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've read multiple answers to similar questions on this topic but I cannot find any explanation for my specific problem. I want to create an event handler that affects all textboxes in my userform (I have 80 textboxes). The following code was used from Overstack help and works with the _Change() control but does not work with _BeforeUpdate (or _AfterUpdate, _Exit, etc.)

Following code in ClassModule:

```
Private WithEvents txtbox As MSForms.TextBox

Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal t As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set txtbox = t
End Property

Private Sub txtbox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox "Worked in Exit"
    Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub txtbox_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox "it worked in BeforeUpdate " & Me.Name
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Code in UserForm:

```
Private myEventHandlers As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim txtbox As mytextbox

    Set myEventHandlers = New Collection

    Dim c As Control
    For Each c In Me.Controls

        If c.Name Like "TextBox*" Then
            Set txtbox = New mytextbox

            Set txtbox.TextBox = c

            myEventHandlers.Add txtbox

        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995931/unable-to-capture-afterupdate-event-with-a-custom-event-handler

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202856/how-to-use-after-update-for-textbox-in-a-class-module  has a (working?) solution